# Wireless Broadcom BCM43228 on an Acer Aspire v5-571p does not work

Tags: wireless, broadcom, acer

My built-in wireless card doesn't switch on. I have run out of ideas to enable it, or install the driver. When I run `rfkill`, it shows no hard block or no soft block. I have been trying this for days, and I don't know what to do now.
I have also looked for instructions; no help there.

`lspci -v` returns the following:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n 
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e04b 
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19 Memory at f0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K] 
Capabilities: <access denied> Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

Comment: I think you have the right driver for it... It [appears to be supported](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/pci/14e4:4359/). There is some commands listed [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2084508), which might help. Is this only occuring when the laptop is on battery power or what - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2140655

Comment: Its all the time just can't see any wireless functions at all

Comment: i have tried the commands that where on the link and none of them have worked i dont know what to do next as i cannot access and internet connection on the laptop ubuntu is on

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your WI-FI is hard blocked in BIOS? As it sounds like since access is denied.

On first boot screen enter BIOS

When in BIOS search for wireless and enable it if needed (Configuration -> wireless -> enabled)

Reboot

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: I have looked and I cannot find wireless in the BIOS

Comment: Well, it has to be somewhere in BIOS try under configuration section. Or Google your version of BIOS to find where Wireless configuration is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having **Dual Boot** then boot in the windows and switch on wifi , see if it works . If it works dont Off it just reboot into Ubuntu and try to On it by pressing the assigned keyboard keys.

If that did not work, Check the Output of -

```
rfkill list all
```

Now by the time as you have used wifi on windows it will detect your Wifi now -

1. If its Soft blocked use  `rfkill unblock wifi` to Switch it on.
2. If its Hard Blocked then try to switch it on physically by pressing desired keybord keys for wifi.

**Also** open Ubuntu-Software-Center and go to edit-Software Sources - Addition Drivers and check the Wifi Driver in my case as shown below -

[image]

And also one of the most important thing Open **BIOS** and check wifi is enabled or not.

Hopefully it should be working.

Comment: Unfourtunatly I'm now using dual boot with windows :(

Comment: Read the first line carefully , its saying if you have windows then boot into windows and switch on your wifi use it , then without turning wifi off restart and then check if "rfkill list all" detects your adapter.

Comment: @Sushantp606 I suspect they meant "not", not "now".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Acer Aspire 5520G running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I noticed that if you put a USB Wireless Dongle, the wirelss adaptor goes on and enable wirelss appears in the dropdown menu! I am then able to us my USB wireless / Modem (Alcatel One Touch x230D) to connect to the net! the on-board built in adaptor then comes on, then it is difficult to connect to the internet with it alone, while the USB device is connected. The good news is that the Alcatel One Touch x230D works in Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

This wireless Broadcom BCM43228 adapter will work with proper drivers.

They can be installed by running

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

in terminal.